# Using react native with hooks, how to get picker value?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to convert a react app to react native.

For my picker, I am able to show the values, but when I click on a value, I get a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value'`.  I know `e.target.value` is not correct, but what value should it be?

```
  const handleDiceTypeInput = e => {
    setDiceType(e.target.value);
  };
```

```
        <Picker
          selectedValue={diceType}
          style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
          onValueChange={handleDiceTypeInput}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="" value="" />  
          <Picker.Item label="D2" value="2" />  
          <Picker.Item label="D4" value="4" />                         
        </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `Picker` [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#onvaluechange). Change it to

```js
 const handleDiceTypeInput = (inputValue) => {
    setDiceType(inputValue);
  };
```